# iOS JSON auth token request says missing parameter

Tags: objective-c, ios, json

I have been looking all over and cannot seem to figure this out.
none of the JSON examples i see have the method name in the url so i think that may be an issue.
here is my code:

```
NSString *username = @"xxxx";
NSString *password = @"xxxx";
NSString *loginURL = @"http://www.xxxxxx.com/services/api/rest/json?method=xxxxxx.auth.gettoken";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:loginURL];

NSString *JSONString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"username\":\"%@\",\"password\":\"%@\"}", username, password];

NSData *JSONBody = [JSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest *loginRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
loginRequest.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
loginRequest.HTTPBody = JSONBody;

NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:loginRequest 
                                   queue:queue 
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){

                           // Manage the response here.
                           NSString *txt = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                           NSLog(@"%@", txt);
                       }];
```

i am snooping the reuest using SquidMan and i noticed that the access log lists:
www.xxxxx.com/services/api/rest/json? - DIRECT/.....
the method name is not there, this is my first time using SquidMan for this but i would assume it would be there.

the message i get back is that parameter username is missing.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, i did not write the webservice and apparently sending it the data in JSON format is wrong.
if i post the data in the format "&param=value&param2=value2" it works.

```
    NSString *JSONString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&username=%@&password=%@",
                      [username stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                      [password stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSData *JSONBody = [JSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableURLRequest *loginRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
loginRequest.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
loginRequest.HTTPBody = JSONBody;
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you haven't specified the `Content-Type` for your request, so the server doesn't know how to interpret the data. Try adding this line to your code after you allocate your `loginRequest`:

```
[loginRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, still doesn't work though. same missing parameter return value. i will leave your suggestion in my code.